# Excel Formula - Sumif OR

Tags: excel, formulas

A challenge for the excel users:
I have a table with the following columns:

```
Year || Week || Output
2011 ||  50  || 1000
2011 ||  51  || 2000
2011 ||  52  || 1500
2012 ||  01  || 1200
2012 ||  02  || 1700
2012 ||  03  || 1900
```

I want to sum the values on the column output that are between a given year/week and another year/week. Example:

- between 2011/50 and 2011/52. Result = 1000+2000+1500 = 4500
- between 2011/51 and 2012/02. Result = 2000+1500+1200+1700 = 6400

Thank you all in advance.

Regards,
MH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My steps:

1. Year = A, Week = B, Output = E
2. Create a temp column (C) holding: `{Year}*100 + {Week}`
3. Create two input sets for the boundaries (also with `{Year}*100 + {Week}`) -- `<LOW>` & `<HIGH>`.
4. Create a temp column (D) with this formula:

`=IF(AND(C2>=<LOW>,C2<=<HIGH>),1,0)*E2`

Then the summation cell becomes:

`=SUM(D:D)`

**EDIT**:  Found another way with no `D` column from above

```
N1 = LOW   (year*100 + week)
O1 = HIGH  (year*100 + week)

N2 => =TEXT(N1)
O2 => =TEXT(O1)
```

`=SUMIFS(E:E,C:C, CONCATENATE(">=",  $N$2),C:C, CONCATENATE("<=",  $O$2))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUMIFS()`, in case that you're using Excel 2007 or above.

Example

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C7, A2:A7, "=2011", B2:B7, ">49", B2:B7, "<53")
```

Otherwise you can still use Excel Macros.

Comment: This will fail when the year changes.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. How could sum intervals that have different years? Ex.: 2011_50 to 2012_02?

Comment: think about doing (year * 53 + week).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in A1:C6, you can do this with an array formula (enter using Shift+Ctrl+Enter):

```
=SUM((A1:A6=2011)*(B1:B6>=50)*(B1:B6<=52)*(C1:C6))
```

Or, with SumProduct (enter as normal):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A6=2011)*(B1:B6>=50)*(B1:B6<=52)*(C1:C6))
```

Obviously, you'll need to enter or reference your criteria. Also, if the year will change then you'll need another term to check the max year.

Comment: Doesn't your sumproduct need commas not stars?